# Error downloading gadm shapefile through R

Tags: r, spatial

I'm trying to download a shapefile for Norway using gadm (from the geodata package)

However, I am encountering the following error:

> "Error in file(con, "r") :    cannot open the connection to
> 'https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.1.txt' In addition: Warning
> message: In file(con, "r") :   URL
> 'https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.1.txt': status was 'HTTP
> response code said error'"

I see nothing online about the service being down at the moment and I can still access the gadm.org website. What can I do here?

Thanks in advance!

I tried to run the below code:

```
norway <- geodata::gadm(country = "NOR", level = 0, 
               path = tempdir(),
               version = "latest")
```

Comment: At the moment it works for me; perhaps a temporary service issue. Can you access https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/ ?

Comment: Yes, I can access it.

Comment: And at the time writing, you are still having issues with geodata package ? If yes, I'm afraid it is not reproducible for others. If the issue remains, perhaps consider `giscoR::gisco_get_countries()` or `rnaturalearth::ne_countries() ` as alternatives.